# Bootstrap 3.1 affix scroll-spy content staying visible when using overflow

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am implementing a table of contents (TOC) in sidebar using bootstrap 3.1 and scroll-spy.  It generally works great, but sometimes I have enough page content that the TOC gets too long to present entirely in the viewport.  So I tweaked the height to be 100% with overflow-y: 100% so the user can still at least scroll entire TOC.

However, as user scrolls down the page, the highlighted element "scrolls' off the TOC's visible view, so the question is, how can I scroll the TOC contents along with the page once the user has scrolled sufficiently far down the page that highlighting in the TOC is no longer visible?

```
<div id='sidebar', style="height: 100%; overflow-y: auto">
  <div id='toc' data-offset-top='250' data-spy='affix'>
    <ul class='nav'>
      <li class='active'><a href="#toc-title">Example</a></li>
      <li><a href="#toc-title">Example 2</a></li>
      <!-- Lots more links here -->
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this it install jquery pluging animatescroll:  http://plugins.compzets.com/animatescroll/ and then use the following:

```
$('#sidebar').on('activate.bs.scrollspy', function () {
  item = $('#toc').find(".active").first();
  item.animatescroll({element: '#toc', padding:20});
});
```

This will keep the active table of contents row visible.  the activate.bs.scrollspy is fired every time a new item becomes active and the animatescroll call moves it to (in this case) 20px from top.